# Error during bulk load in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, bulk-load

I am trying to use bulk insert for a .txt file, which is separated using a comma, but a few columns also have a double quotes, because of which when bulk insert is used, some rows are not inserted properly.

I am using bulk insert with fmt file but it still gives me error: Cannot bulk load. Invalid column number in the format file "\server\Data\Transfer\formatfile1.fmt".

I am out of options to think what is wrong with the format file that I have created.

Here is the data in .txt format

```
"NUMBER","DATE","JOIN_NUMBER","CEO","FAX","ACTNUM"
1,3/31/2005 0:00:00,2,,"9037983933",5
6,3/31/2005 0:00:00,7,,"5048899070",7
7,3/31/2005 0:00:00,8,,"2289384313",7
12,3/31/2005 0:00:00,11,"Tom Johnson, SVP","8607611980",8
13,3/31/2005 0:00:00,12,,"2252146851",3
```

This is the formatfile:

```
13.0
6
1       SQLCHAR 0       5        ",\""      1     NUMBER        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR 0       50  ",\""       2     DATE      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR 0       20  ",\""       3     JOIN_NUMBER   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR 0       500 "\",\""     4     CEO       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR 0       12  "\",\""     5     Fax       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR 0       10  "\"\r\n"    6     ACTNUM        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

I am using SQL Server 2016.

This is the sql code I am trying to use for bulk insert:

```
GO 
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF 
GO

BULK INSERT FDICDev.dbo.fs220D_test
FROM '\\server\Data\Transfer\textdata.txt'
WITH    ( FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    FORMATFILE = '\\server\Data\Transfer\formatfile1.fmt'    )
```

Can someone point out what is the issue going on here!!!

Comment: Why do you have `",\""` in your format file in the first three rows?

Comment: Shouldn't it be there since it is comma delimited.

Comment: Comma delimited is just `","`.   Why do you have the extra `\"` in there?

Comment: I had referred this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2010/02/04/how-to-remove-unwanted-quotation-marks-while-importing-a-data-file/

and it shows "\" to be used after comma for this purpose: Each character column data is separated by “,”. So, each column’s delimiter is given as “\”,\””. The “\” character is an escape sequence tells BCP that the character following the backslash is part of the delimiter

Comment: And that would be great if all of your columns had quotes around them, but since it's only some of them, you have to be judicious about where you use them.  I cited the exact same tutorial in my answer.  So I think you just didn't read it carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your format file is wrong.  You have told it to expect a double-quote character as part of the column terminator of, well, every column.  However, only your 5th and 6th columns are quote-qualified.

The terminators that are just a comma should be represented with `","`.

Only if a quote character is expected on either side of the comma should you include the `\"`.

[Here's a helpful tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2010/02/04/how-to-remove-unwanted-quotation-marks-while-importing-a-data-file/).